# how to create automatic build generation for xamarin.forms project?

Tags: git, azure, xamarin.forms, visual-sourcesafe

How I can generate builds for android and ios from xamarin forms automatically. I want that I upload my code on git or svn or vss or azure or some other repository and then it create builds itself there and distribute it.

Is it possible for xamrain forms? If yes then how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the continuous deployment for your xamarin.forms app, you could refer to the two ways to enable continuous deployment from BitBucket, GitHub, etc.

1. Use **Deployment options** in your xamarin.forms app in the portal, you could refer to the screenshot to configure it.

[image]

2. Use **Deployment Center (Preview)** in the portal, you could refer to the screenshot, it is a preview version, it provides the deployment with more details, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service-mobile%2Ftoc.json).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use app center. https://appcenter.ms/

Connect to your source repository, VSTS, GitHub, and Bitbucket are currently supported, and setting up your continuous integration is as easy as clicking a couple of buttons.